# Redirecting certain 404s to a page, handling all others as normal

Tags: redirect, 404

I'm having trouble setting things up to redirect some old news articles a certain way, while still serving existing articles:

> If a page exists at `/news/my-article` then it should be served as normal.
>
> If that URL *doesn't* exist (ie, all non-functioning `/news/*` URLs), I want the user to be redirected to `/news`.
>
> All 404s that aren't within `/news` should be handled as normal.

My first thought was to use a `redirect` tag in the 404 template, only if the request URL matches `/news/*`... but I'm not sure if that's too late in the process. By that time, has a 404 header already been sent, so the user would get 404 -> 301 -> 404 ?

Comment: Your first thought was my first thought, too. Have you tried it?

Comment: I think it is working, yes... just testing a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also set up a route for `news/{slug}` to point to your news template, and have it do the check to see if the entry in `segment_2` is valid, and do something based on that.

I did something like this for my "members" pages:

```
 {% set thisProfile = craft.users.id(craft.request.segment(2))[0] %}

 {% if not thisProfile %}
    {% redirect siteUrl %}
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Nice, I like this, thanks khalwat! These news articles are actually within categories, so in the template, if the Entry doesn't exist, I can redirect to the category. This seems a more logical place for this stuff than in the 404 template.